# Algorithm that will maintain top n items in the past k days?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I would like to implement a data structure maintaining a set `S` for a leaderboard that can answer the following queries efficiently, while also being memory-efficient:

1. `add(x, t)` Add a new item with score `x` to set `S` with an associated time `t`.
2. `query(u)` List the top `n` items (sorted by score) in the set `S` which has associated time `t` such that `t + k >= u`.  Each subsequent query will have a `u` no smaller than previous queries.

In standard English, highscores can be added to this leaderboard individually, and I'd like an algorithm that can efficiently query the top `n` items on the leaderboard within the post `k` days (where `k` and `n` are fixed constants).

`n` can be assumed to be much less than the total number of items, and scores may be assumed to be random.

A naïve algorithm would be to store all elements as they are added into a balanced binary search tree sorted by score, and remove elements from the tree when they are more than `k` days old. Detecting elements that are more than `k` days old can be done with another balanced binary search tree sorted by time.  This algorithm would yield a good time complexity of `O(log(h))` where `h` is the total number of scores added in the past `k` days.  However, the space complexity is `O(h)`, and it is easy to see that most of the data saved will never be reported in a query even if no new scores are added for the next `k` days.

If `n` is 1, a simple double-ended queue is all that is necessary.  Before adding a new item to the front of the queue, remove items from the front that have a smaller score than the new item, because they will never be reported in a query.  Before querying, remove items from the back of the queue that are too old, then return the item that is left at the back of the queue.  All operations would be amortized constant time complexity, and I wouldn't be storing items that would never be reported.

When `n` is more than 1, I can't seem to be able to formulate an algorithm which has a good time complexity and only stores items that could possibly be reported.  An algorithm with time complexity `O(log(h))` would be great, but `n` is small enough so that `O(log(h) + n)` is acceptable too.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you add items in ascending order by t?

Comment: Most of the time, but I don't want to preclude the possibility of network delays, needing to update a second server, and other things that might cause a desync.  But if you have an algorithm that only works if you add items in ascending order, that would be good too.

Comment: an idea: make a quadtree

Comment: Can we also consider k to be small?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic Because I'm going to count by seconds instead of days, k will be large, likely larger than h.

Comment: @user31264 Could you explain how I can use a quadtree for this problem?

Comment: If t is always increasing and x is always decreasing, every (x, t) will be reported. So I guess that no algorithm could make the worst case space complexity smaller than O(h).

Comment: @MoTao I'm aware of that, so I mentioned that scores may be assumed to be random.  While the worst case space complexity will not be smaller than O(h), the average space complexity could be a lot less.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on the double-ended queue solution and I assume t is ascending.

The idea is that a record can be removed if there are n records with both larger t and larger x than it, which is implemented by `Record.count` in the sample code.

As each record would be moved from `S` to `temp` at most n times, we have average time complexity O(n).
The space complexity is hard to decide. However, it looks fine in the simulation. `S.size()` is about 400 when h = 10000 and n = 50.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int k = 10000, n = 50;

class Record {
public:
    Record(int _x, int _t): x(_x), t(_t), count(n) {}
    int x, t, count;
};

deque<Record> S;

void add(int x, int t)
{
    Record record(x, t);
    vector<Record> temp;
    while (!S.empty() && record.x >= S.back().x) {
        if (--S.back().count > 0) temp.push_back(S.back());
        S.pop_back();       
    }
    S.push_back(record);
    while (!temp.empty()) {
        S.push_back(temp.back());
        temp.pop_back();
    }
}

vector<int> query(int u)
{
    while (S.front().t + k < u)
        S.pop_front();
    vector<int> xs;
    for (int i = 0; i < S.size() && i < n; ++i)
        xs.push_back(S[i].x);
    return xs;
}

int main()
{
    for (int t = 1; t <= 1000000; ++t) {
        add(rand(), t);
        vector<int> xs = query(t);
        if (t % k == 0) {
            cout << "t = " << t << endl;
            cout << "S.size() = " << S.size() << endl;
            for (auto x: xs) cout << x << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks great!  But I think the for-loop in the `query` function should also check if records are too old, i.e. ignore/discard records if `S[i].t + k < u`.  While the front-most record may be added recently, other records in `S` might be older than it.

Comment: @Bernard The check `S[i].t + k < u` seems unnecessary as `t` is ascending in `S`. BTW, remember to accept this answer if it does help.

Comment: Could you please explain why that would be so? I fail to see how `t` might be ascending. The `add()` function only ensures that `x` is ascending in `S`. `t` is only guaranteed to be ascending in `S` when `n = 1`. Consider the following values of `x`, inserted with increasing `t`: `999999`, `999998`, `999997`, `999996`, ... , until the oldest record (`999999`) almost expires.  Then insert `1000000` (larger than everything else). None of the current records will be removed, and the new record will be placed at the very front.  If you query after `999999` expires, `query()` will still return it.

Comment: I'll accept the answer once this is resolved because right now the code doesn't seem right to me.